# Getting the following error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.wrapRefArray([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray;

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-java-interop, scala-2.13, scalatest-maven-plugin

Getting the following error :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:scala.Predef$.wrapRefArray([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray;

I'm not sure about the nature of the error but I believe it has to do something after it tried to update my scala version to 2.13, if anyone knows a fix it will be appreciated.

pom.xml snippet

```
    <scala.version>2.13.1</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.13</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>4.9.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: check if this solves - https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/scala-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-compiler-message/